# DocuSign.eSign.dll package for dotnet core

Tags: .net-core, docusignapi

Is there any dotnet core version of DocuSign.eSign Nuget package? or even source code I can fork?

[DocuSign.eSign Nuget pacakge](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/)

[Source code for C# client](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out both suggested solutions, it turns out that .net core SDK does not support the JWT Oauth workflow and it only support what's called legacy authentication method.

So, If you are trying to use JWT authentication using dotnet core SDK, you cannot

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any officially provided by DocuSign or alternatives that I'm aware of.

You could generate your own library with [Swagger CodeGen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) and the [DocuSign OpenAPI Specifications Swagger JSON](https://github.com/docusign/eSign-OpenAPI-Specification)

Comment: Thanks Andrew. This seems the way to go. Has this done before? I am looking for potential obstacles that I need to be aware of.

Comment: I've used Swagger CodeGen with success on other projects, I have not used it with the DocuSign OpenAPI Specification.

Comment: I just gave it a try using below command 
" java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.2.1.jar generate -i .\esignature.rest.swagger.json -lcsharp"  but there is no jwt authentication methods generated in the output code. I also could find dotnetcore language support. Any thoughts?

Comment: `java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.2.1.jar generate -i .\esignature.rest.swagger.json -l aspnetcore` I believe aspnetcore will work

Comment: got an exception `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: aspnetcore`

Answer (score 0):

There is an unofficial fork of the C# SDK for .NET Core. Check the issues for the DocuSign C# SDK for a link.

Also, I'm looking to conduct 30 minute interviews with developers who are using DocuSign or considering to do so to get their opinions on how I can improve the developer products. Contact me via larry.kluger.docusign@gmail.com if you'd like more info.

Comment: Thanks Larry. Would there be any security concerns to use an unofficial fork of SDK for an enterprise application?

Comment: Hi @Broomandan, the DocuSign engineering team did not produce the .NET Core fork so we can't take responsibility for it. It is open source, so your InfoSec team can make its own decision. Please tell your DocuSign technical/business contact to add your company/org' interest to the .NET Core project: DCM-2161. That will help it happen sooner. Thank you.